# Synchronous phase value for CERN LHC

Tags: large-hadron-collider, radio-frequency, cavity-qed

How to find out that the value of the synchronous phase for CERN LHC in the case where beams undergo collision, and the RF cavities provide only longitudinal focusing with no net acceleration.

Comment: Is this a beam diagnostics question? LHC bunch lengths are on the order of 300-600mm, if I remember correctly. Distance between bunches should be something like 5m (60MHz bunch frequency). Beam alignment and phase is continuously measured by something like a thousand beam monitors and a variety of real time feedback loops is used to center the collision point in the detectors. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: It isn't simple. https://cds.cern.ch/record/2686976?ln=en